# Bigcommerce webhooks not firing to request bin

Tags: webhooks, bigcommerce

I have successfully created bigcommerce webhooks but can't seem to get any data sending to a requestb.in

```
{
   "id"=><webhook_id>, 
   "client_id"=><client_id>,
   "store_hash"=><store_hash>, 
   "scope"=>"store/product/created", 
   "destination"=>"https://requestb.in/1ieyzm31", 
   "headers"=>{"X-ANT-SHARED-TOKEN"=>nil}, 
   "is_active"=>true, 
   "created_at"=>1493173043, 
   "updated_at"=>1493173043
}
```

The docs say that the is_active flag will flip off if the webhook fails to send. Im not getting any data and the flag remains. Is there a bug BC side!?!?

UPDATE:

I tested the SSL certs of requestbin on the tool BC recommends, because big commerce said it might ignore webhooks if SSL is not set up correctly

Scored: A
[image]

Comment: Are you responding to webhooks in any fashion such as with a 200?

Comment: request bin will always respond with a 200. Even if Im not, the docs say the is_active flag will turn off if I respond with anything other than 200. Because the flag remains on it indicates that the webhook never sent

Comment: Just a guess here - but I don't think requestb.in is working for webhooks because it returns `Content-Type: text/html` instead of `Content-Type: application/json`. I would see 1 successful POST to request bin and then nothing else. When I implemented my own endpoint, it worked like a charm.